# Unable to run npm, node from bash in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have setup my integrated terminal to be bash as shown below:

```
{
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
}
```

Bash is working but when I try to run things like npm, node, ect it says the command is not found. If I run the standalone git bash.exe (not the one in the bin folder) it works correctly but you have to run the one in the bin folder to have it integrated, what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login","-i"]` to your settings.  You may have noticed git bash.exe runs with these arguments.

[image]

I had a similar issue (missing arguments) when setting up an integrated terminal with Visual Studio - although I haven't had a problem with VSCode.